# How to ImageIdentify multiple objects in a single image?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning

Suppose an [image](http://www.preparefordinner.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/apricot-apple-banana-pudding.jpg) has multiple objects:

[image: apricot-apple-banana]

`ImageIdentify` only finds the banana:

```
im = Import["https://wolfr.am/6-m8QtHj"];
ImageIdentify[im]
```

returns

```
Entity["Concept","Banana::f6z73"]
```

If I crop around the apple, it finds it:

```
im2 = ImageTake[,{1,100},{100,200}];
ImageIdentify[im2]
```

returns

```
Entity["Concept","RedDelicious::xxzy3"]
```

But if I ask for 5 identifications, it still doesn't find the apple:

```
ImageIdentify[im,All,5]
```

returns

```
{Entity["Concept","EdibleFruit::5d4pn"],
 Entity["Concept","Banana::f6z73"],
 Entity["Concept","Fruit::855t9"],
 Entity["Concept","ReproductiveStructure::66t28"],
 Entity["Concept","GardenTruck::f8248"]
 }
```

Thoughts?

Comment: For me, using `ImageIdentify[%, Entity["Concept", "Fruit::855t9"], 3, 
 SpecificityGoal -> 1]` finds all three fruit perfectly.

Comment: Wonderful! That answers my question. Can you turn your comment into an answer so I can upvote it? Also, how did you know the magic code to add after "Fruit::" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ImageIdentify[%, Entity["Concept", "Fruit::855t9"], 3, SpecificityGoal -> 1]
```

I'm not really sure how robust this is, though. (I got "Fruit::855t9" by using the `Ctrl`+`=` input, and typing `fruit`.)

Comment: Thanks! How did you figure out the `855t9` to put after "Fruit"?

Comment: Ah, I see that `ImageIdentify[%,"fruit",3,SpecificityGoal -> 1]` works too.

Comment: I've edited it in.

Comment: Update: Two years later, it appears ImageIdentify no longer gives the correct output. In Sep 2015 it returned `{banana, rose apple, nectarine}`, now it gives `{banana, citrus, mango}`. :-/.